# The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows without any JOINS

Tags: mysql, mariadb

In MariaDB 11 database I have following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id`         int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `domain_id`  int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `type`       varchar(20)      NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name`       varchar(100)     NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `count`      int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `created_at` timestamp            NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp            NULL DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tags_type_index`        (`type`),
  KEY `tags_domain_id_foreign` (`domain_id`),
  KEY `tags_name_index`        (`name`),
  KEY `tags_count_index`       (`count`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `tags_domain_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`domain_id`) REFERENCES `domains` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

My query is following:

```
select
    *
from
    tags
where
    type = 'tag'
    and
    domain_id = 95
limit 10;
```

The total number of rows with this query is: 58,131 (without limit). Total number of records in the table is 1,466,914 rows.
Total number for this domain_id is: 86,871 rows.

I'm using `MAX_JOIN_SIZE` in my database to mitigate some issue with poorly optimized queries in a complex web app.

The issue I'm trying to understand why this causes error: "The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows" when I set `SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE = 100000;`?

It works however with: `SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE = 200000;`.

I'm curious cause firstly there is no joins in this query, secondly total rows number for `type = 'tag' and domain_id = 95` is 58,131.

Explain query returns:

```json
{ "id": 1, "select_type": "SIMPLE", "table": "tags", "type": "ref", "possible_keys": "tags_type_index,tags_domain_id_foreign", "key": "tags_domain_id_foreign", "key_len": "4", "ref": "const", "rows": "166160", "Extra": "Using where" }
```

Comment: "_I'm using `MAX_JOIN_SIZE` in my database to mitigate some issue with poorly optimized queries in a complex web app._" - Why can't you fix those first and avoid this problem entirely?

Comment: Before MySQL 8.0.31, `max_join_size` also applies to single-table queries: **MySQL 8.0.30 and earlier: Do not permit statements that probably need to examine more than max_join_size rows (for single-table statements) or row combinations (for multiple-table statements) or that are likely to do more than max_join_size disk seeks.**

Comment: Please add the result of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: @Dai this is what I'm doing, here above is an example of the query that I want to fix.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, but why it errors on max_join_size=100000 when total rows is 58000? But it works when max_join_size=200000.

Comment: @GeorgRichter   {
    "id": 1,
    "select_type": "SIMPLE",
    "table": "tags",
    "type": "ref",
    "possible_keys": "tags_type_index,tags_domain_id_foreign",
    "key": "tags_domain_id_foreign",
    "key_len": "4",
    "ref": "const",
    "rows": "166160",
    "Extra": "Using where"
  } However if I run `select count(*) from `tags` where `type` = 'tag' and `domain_id` = 95 limit 10;` it returns 58152. Interesting why it says then `"rows": "166160",`. If I run just `select count(*) from `tags` where `type` = 'tag' and `domain_id` = 95 limit 10;` it's 86854, around 1/2 of 166160.

Comment: Please post it as formatted text in the question, it's not easily readable in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the number of rows in the result set is below the value of `max_join_size` the server needs to access more than `max_join_size` rows to deliver the result.

Let's assume you have two identical tables t1 and t2 with one integer column without an index and 1000 identical unique values.

`SELECT a FROM t1 JOIN t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id` will return exact one row, but to get the result the server needs to compare 1000 x 1000 values.

Your EXPLAIN output shows that the server needs to examine 166160 rows, which is over the size of max_join_size.

See also [sql_big_selects](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#sql_big_selects) and [max_join_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#max_join_size) documentation.

Comment: There's no join in the query, so there's no multiplication involved.

Comment: In my example there is a join, in the original statement there isn't.

Comment: That's my point. You're answering a different question, it doesn't explain why the OP is getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

Query execution can only use one index to optimize the `WHERE` clause. According to your `EXPLAIN` result, it has chosen to use the index on the `domain_id` column. There are 166160 rows with `domain_id = 95`, it has to scan all of these to find the ones that also have `type = 'tag'`. This is more than `max_join_size`, so you get an error.

Create a composite index with both columns, then the query can be satisfied entirely with the index.

```
ALTER TABLE tags ADD INDEX `tags_type_domain_index` (type, domain_id);
```

If you do this, you can drop the index on `type`, since a multi-column index serves as an index for all of its prefixes as well.

Comment: Thanks, but I have 86k rows for that domain, this query `select count(*) from tags where domain_id = 95;` returns: 86869. So it's less than 100000. I'll try composite index, that can solve this!

Comment: I added `tags_type_domain_index`, however the error is still the same, here is explain: `  {"id": 1, "select_type": "SIMPLE", "table": "tags", "type": "ref", "possible_keys": "tags_domain_id_foreign,tags_type_domain_index", "key": "tags_type_domain_index", "key_len": "86", "ref": "const,const", "rows": "124044", "Extra": "Using where; Using index"}`. I'm curious where this number 124044 comes from, cause I have less rows in total for that domain_id (86871).

Comment: There is another example that doesn't make sense: `SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE = 200000;`, `select count(id) as total, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") as day from transactions where event = 'RenewalSuccess' and created_at >= '2022-06-29 00:00:00' and created_at <= '2023-06-29 00:00:00' group by day;` this error works ok, but  explain query gives `{"possible_keys": "ccbill_logs_event_index,transactions_created_at_idx", "key": null, "key_len": null, "rows": "251029"}`. Curious why it doesn't error if `"rows": "251029"`? It errors however when I set `SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE = 100000;`. Trying to make sense

Comment: Sorry, I can't explain these results, maybe it's a MySQL bug. Submit a bug report and maybe they can figure it out.